# make http call from within another http call in angular

Tags: angularjs

I call an http service, loop through the results and each item acts as the key for another http-call.

What's the best way to do that?

I guess calling $http from within another $http call does not work as the outer $http-loop may just exit before the inner $http calls
have finished?

// pseudo code:

```
$http.get(url).then((response) ->
  foreach response.data as item
        $http.get(item.url).then((response) ->
          foreach response.data as item
        )
  return result
)
```

Doesn't really work, right?

Comment: I am not sure but what is your concern, but all http calls would be made irrespective of loop or function exiting. If you want some type of coordination, then you need to provide more details.

Comment: If you bind to `$scope` inside the `then`, it shouldn't matter when the response is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine, but you need to collect the sub-responses in an array or object and return $q.all(sub-responses) to ensure the caller waits for them to resolve.

Sticking to your pseudo-code I think it looks like:

```
$http.get(url).then((response) ->
 var r = [];
 foreach response.data as item
    r.push($http.get(item.url))
 return $q.all(r).then((subs) -> foreach ...)
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

This psuedo code will work fine.  The `then` is a callback for the async operation.  See [promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) in angular for more detail.

You are correct that the flow of the code execution will continue, but the callback (`then`) will still fire when the response is returned.

So, this means that if you are binding to `$scope` inside the `then`, all will be fine and the data will bind into the model.